# How to run a recursive trigger in SSMS successfully

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have the following trigger that needs to execute recursively 30 times

```
ALTER TRIGGER testTrigger 
   ON dbo.TestTable 
   AFTER INSERT,DELETE,UPDATE
   AS 
   BEGIN
  -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
  -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    Declare @counter int
    SET @counter = 1
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[TestTable]
       ([id]
       ,[data]
       ,[counter]
       ,[flag])
 VALUES
       (1
       ,'data'
       ,@counter
       ,'T')
    Set @counter = @counter+1
    if(@counter=30)
    Return
-- Insert statements for trigger here
SET NOCOUNT OFF;

END
GO
```

This is the insert statement I am using to fire it

```
 INSERT INTO [dbo].[TestTable]
         ([id]
         ,[data]
         ,[counter]
         ,[flag])
    VALUES
         (1
          ,'data'
          ,1
          ,'T')
```

I get the following error,

**Maximum stored procedure, function, trigger, or view nesting level exceeded (limit 32).**
The Nested trigger is ON and Recursive trigger is also ON. I explicitly need the trigger to run recursively.

Comment: Why do you want it to run recursively?

Comment: I would like to poll a web service 30 times and then update the table for 30 different records received from the web service. At the end of the poll web service will send a confirmation which upon receiving the trigger would stop executing.

Comment: The last place you should be doing such logic is in a `TRIGGER`; it will be awful for performance and have a huge detrimental effect on any DML operations on your table `dbo.TestTable `. This is logic for your application layer, not the RDBMS.

Comment: Your `@counter` variable will not be populated into next triggers, thereby nothing will stop the recursion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can control nested trigger level by using `TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL` at the top of your trigger:

```
IF ((SELECT TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL()) > 31)
            RETURN
```

so your trigger can look like this :

```
ALTER TRIGGER testTrigger
ON dbo.TestTable
AFTER INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE
AS
    BEGIN
        IF (   (
                   SELECT
                       TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL()
               ) > 31
           )
            RETURN;
        -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
        -- interfering with SELECT statements.
        SET NOCOUNT ON;

        INSERT INTO [dbo].[TestTable]
            (
                [id]
                , [data]
                , [flag]
            )
        VALUES
            (
                1, 'data', 'T'
            );

        RETURN;
        -- Insert statements for trigger here
        SET NOCOUNT OFF;

    END;
GO
```